# Default.png working in simulator but not in device?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

When the app loads, if we want an image to be displayed we use one named Default.png. And I used it for icon too. But are working fine in simulator.

But when I try it in device at both places its blank. Can anyone sort me out of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple HIG your Icon.png should be of 57 x 57 pixels, with 90 degree corners.
and Default.png should be of 320 x 480 pixels.For more info follow [MobileHIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

For splash screen

1. Add simply a Default.png to your project’s Resource folder.

For icon

2.Add a icon.png to your Info.plist

i.e. Key = Icon file , Value = icon.png

3.If all this doesn't work then delete the build folder and rebuild your application (but before build press Clean All button in xcode).

4.If this also doesn't work the change image name to default.png ( not Default.png)

Comment: It was a problem with the image. Seeing you iterate all the steps that i have done made me confirmed that what i were doing was right. So checked the image and it was corrupted. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: I am happy to see you have got the solution finally.

Comment: I tried cleaning first.  Didn't work.  Once I deleted the build folder is was fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your project using this button

[alt text http://grab.by/1AzW](http://grab.by/1AzW)

And then reinstall the app...

Comment: Thanks for showing this button. I clean-all really often but never thought of putting it on my toolbar! I also think this answers Wolverine's quiestion if he is using a png file called `Default.png`. Anyway, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the case of the file. It needs to have a capital D. On the simulator Default.png and default.png are the same but not on the device.

Comment: Ya, its capital D only. But to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the application from the device and reinstalling. I know, silly, but sometime's fixes xcode/device issues.

Comment: Tried it so many times to no result. Even after doing all correctly, don't understand whats with it now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the size of your Default.png is 320*480 and if you have converted it from any other format, make sure you have not just renamed but properly re-saved the image in png format.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it's because of the "capital D" issue.
I've seen the same problem with UIImageView.

Comment: Well, if you've had an issue with filenames, it had nothing to do with `UIImageView`, which, as a View object, is ignorant of the file its image came from. You may have had this issue with `UIImage`, though. I am being sort of nit-picky, but accuracy is important.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem today but due to the way I added the Localized Default.png files.  I manually put them in their respective en.lproj and fr.lproj directories on disks and then I added them to xcode which was properly showing them as Localized.  They were showing up properly in the simulator but I only got a black screen on the real devices.

I removed them from XCode, put the english ones directly in my resource folder, added them to XCode and marked them as Localized from in there.  It then started to work.

This was in XCode 3.2.6 (IOS 4.3).

Comment: next time remove the app from the device first. Most likely this was caused because xcode doesn't delete files and you ended up with 3 Default.png files, and iOS picked the one in the root folder. Because it doesn't look for localized files if a file is present in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

For those who didn't catch correct image on device:

Makes ure that Default.png is ACTUALLY PNG format.
I've saw this problem when my Default.png was .JPEG file that was renamed to .PNG

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and this still didn't work...  Finally I changed my Default.png name to Splash.png and in my info.plist I added 'Launch image' and said it should look for 'Splash'  -  This fixed my problem!